# Reading stdin with scanner without OEF

Tags: go

I'm learning Go and as an initial project, I'm trying the Learntris challenge.

Here you must take input separated by a newline from stdin. I've been reading about readers vs scanners and how scanners are the appropriate level of abstraction for most things.

Here I'm using a scanner to check for single character commands and on the command 'g' I need to read 22 lines separated by '\n'. I think the way I'm treating the scanner might be wrong as I keep receiving empty arrays. my code can be seen here:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "learntris/internal/pkg/matrix"
)

func main() {
    board := matrix.Create_mat()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for scanner.Scan() {

        text := scanner.Text()
        char := text[0]
        switch {
        case char == 'q':
            //quit
            os.Exit(3)
        case char == 'p':
            //print the state of the matrix
            matrix.Print_mat(board)

        case char == 'g':
            given(&board)
            matrix.Print_mat(board)
        default:
            //still quit
            fmt.Println("case not hit")
            os.Exit(3)
        }
    }
}

func given(board *([][]rune)) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    i := 0
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if i == 21 { break} //only read 22 lines
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        //will modify board here once scanner is sorted out 
        i++
    }
}
```

updated given function:

```
func given(board *([][]rune)) {
    //fmt.Println("got to given")
    //expecting 22 lines of 10 items separated by spaces
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    i := 0 //my iterator for num lines(rows)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        //fmt.Println("scanning")
        text := scanner.Text()
        if len(text) >= 10{
            //fmt.Println(text)
            //need to split and throw away spaces
            split_line := strings.Split(text, " ")
            for j, j_str := range(split_line){
                (*board)[i][j] = rune(j_str[0])
            }
            i++

        }

        if i == 22 {break} //stop at 22 lines
    }

}
```

This can take an input like this:

```
g
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
m m m m m m m m m m
b b b b b b b b b b
c c c c c c c c c c
g g g g g g g g g g
y y y y y y y y y y
o o o o o o o o o o
r r r r r r r r r r
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . .
c . . . . . . . . .
c . . . . . . . . .
c . . . . g . . . .
c . . o . g g . . .
. . . o . b g . . .
. m r r o o b y y .
m m m r r b b y y .
p
q
```

passed via standard in. When copy and pasted into the programs input manually, it works fine but when the same text is given via ./learntris < input.txt, it will land in the default in the switch case and never take in the matrix via given.

I think the issue lies in the difference between manual input and streaming over stdin but I'm not sure what I should change.

Final edit:

```
func given(board *([][]rune), scanner *bufio.Scanner) {
    //expecting 22 lines of 10 items separated by spaces
    i := 0 //my iterator for num lines(rows)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        text := scanner.Text()
        if len(text) >= 10{
            //fmt.Println(text)
            //need to split and throw away spaces
            split_line := strings.Split(text, " ")
            for j, j_str := range(split_line){
                (*board)[i][j] = rune(j_str[0])
            }
            i++

        }

        if i == 22 {break} //stop at 22 lines
    }
    if scanner.Err() != nil{
        fmt.Println(scanner.Err())
    }

}
```

by passing the scanner into the function, the scanner no longer lost its intended place and didn't try to consume the matrix as the next command.

Comment: seems to work fine. But you will get an empty string when you hit enter without anything written. If you don't want that, check for empty string and increment the count only when string is not empty

Comment: I may have forgotten to mention, but its an automated input without any actual keyboard intervention. ie ./learntris < input.txt. So in this input there are no empty lines until the end

Comment: I made a sample file with some data and it worked. Sure i'm not missing anything ?

Comment: I updated with my more complete implentation and the example input. It will work copy and pasted as a single block into the stdin of the running program, but not when piped from a text file.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/pR8zeUexa1j The following program gave me this output. https://play.golang.org/p/nTvjKgzUFyf